# Нужна помощь в составлении регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Привет!

Не силен в регулярках, не могу составить правильное. Есть строки с размерами следующего вида:

```
4x(3x1.0) -- задано три размера
5x(3x1.5) -- задано три размера
27x1.5 -- задано два размера
```

Необходимо разобрать строки и получить числа. Составил вот такую регулярку:

```
(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d*.\d+)(?![\d.])
```

Для первых двух строк она работает, но в третьей работает не верно - дробь не верно определяется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну а если просто выделить группы, состоящие из цифр, включая дроби.

```
([\d.]+)
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5bOKZS/1)

Comment: Этот вариант конечно работает, но тогда я не могу определить какое число к какой строке относится. Хотелось бы получить группы для каждой строки, как в примере для двух первых строк получаю.

Comment: А вы не построчно обрабатываете данные?

Comment: О, тут я протупил чего-то. Знакомые подсказали такой вариант: (\d+|)[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+\.\d+)

Comment: @Nova только для строки `27x1.5` получится три группы `('2', '7', '1.5') в вашем варианте.

Comment: Да, и это тоже заметил, поправили, теперь вот такое: (\d*?)[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+\.\d+)